Отслеживание файлов и передача данных в aiogram
Стоит задача отслеживать появление видео в разных домашних папках пользователей linux, и регулярно отправлять видео в бота aiogram. Причем отслеживание нужно начинать только с того момента, когда пользователь создал папку (нажал кнопку создать папку в боте).
Сначала написал простой скрипт на innotify, который рекурсивно отслеживает изменения в папке /home и отправляет на flask сервер запрос с данными об изменении
watcher.py
from inotify.constants import IN_ATTRIB 
from config import BASE_PATH, ENDPOINT_URL
import requests


i = inotify.adapters.InotifyTree("/home/ftp/", mask=IN_ATTRIB )

for event in i.event_gen(yield_nones=False):
    (_, type_names, path, filename) = event
    if "IN_ATTRIB" in type_names:
        data = {
            "type": type_names[0],
            "path": path,
            "file": filename
        }

    requests.post(ENDPOINT_URL, json=data)

flask сервер же добавляет в бд запись об ивенте.
Хотел настроить celery beat но проблема в том, что в celery нельзя динамически добавить задачу, которая будет выполняться по расписанию без перезапуска celery
Мне кажется это не очень подход, может кто подскажет решения лучше?
